# SQL Convert dd/mm/yy to yymmdd

Tags: sql, date

I have been trying to achieve this all day, I have followed numerous tutorials and can't seem to crack it, I have been trying things like:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 131) from Table
```

yet it does not seem to change anything.

Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: `convert(VARCHAR(10), DATE,11)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 12)`

12 is the right code for the format you want. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: is there a way I can use this but reverse the order? So it would be yymmdd?

Comment: @DJONES it is in that order

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
declare @TDATE Date = '2015-11-10';
select Convert(varchar,Datepart(Year, @TDATE))+Convert(varchar,Datepart(Month, @TDATE))+Convert(varchar,Datepart(Day, @TDATE))
```

Output:

```
20151110
```

Answer (score 0):

12 is the right code. Use below query to get output as 'yymmdd'

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 12) from Table

Comment: is there a way I can use this but reverse the order? So it would be yymmdd? it currently returns ddmmyy

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL the easiest way is to use [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
to_char(date, 'yyyymmdd')::int
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to construct the value from date parts.  Here is a numeric conversion:

```
select (year(date) % 100) * 10000) + month(date) * 100 + day(date)
```

It is easy to convert this to a number:

```
select cast( (year(date) % 100) * 10000) + month(date) * 100 + day(date) as varchar(10))
```

The slight advantage to this approach over using `convert` is that a human being can understand the logic without perusing arcane documentation, specific to SQL Server.  I don't know why SQL Server doesn't support a simple format-type function similar to most other databases (and programming languages).

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_format(column_name, '%Y%m%d') from table_name;
```